# DB Modeling - Generic column relationship

Tags: sql, database

I am modeling a new database and I have a problem to keep my db scheme generic in order to make it able to be updated in the future.

I have drawn a simple scheme which reflects the actual problem, let's say that I have an employee table which has all the common info from all employees. In addition, there are one table per possible assignment which all needs an employee with its custom columns. The business logic allows an employee to have different assignments.

[image]

What is the best way to bind each pk of different assignment tables into another table (in this case the Notification table)?

Comment: I don't really think this is a programming problem – maybe dba.stackexchange.com is more your forum? Please read their rules to make sure you're on-topic on their site.

Comment: Data Design questions are generally considered programming questions and so are in-bounds for this site.

Comment: What database are you using?  If you are looking for the "best" way, I would suggest that you investigate table inheritance in Postgres.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'd generally agree, but the way this is asked is very much programming-agnostic – all we know it's going to be a relational DB with the option for the schema to be updated later.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I am using MS SQL Server.